# R: Extracting Numbers from a string separated by comma

Tags: r, substring

I have a data frame for example,

```
X1 12:37  
X2  3,0,0
```

I want to extract 3 0  and 0 individually into a new data frame.

Ne idea how could I do it??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @agstudy's "res1":

```
res1 <- read.table(
  text='X1 12:37
  X2  3,0,0')
temp <- read.table(text = as.character(res1$V2), 
                   sep = ",", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
temp
#      V1 V2 V3
# 1 12:37 NA NA
# 2     3  0  0
temp[complete.cases(temp), ]
#   V1 V2 V3
# 2  3  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can start by reading your Lines ans splitting them to extract Number from row names.

```
ll <- readLines(textConnection('X1 12:37  
X2  3,0,0'))
res <- strsplit(ll,' ')
[[1]]
[1] "X1"    "12:37" ""     

[[2]]
[1] "X2"    ""      "3,0,0"
```

Or using `read.table`:

```
res1 <- read.table(text='X1 12:37  
X2  3,0,0')
  V1    V2
1 X1 12:37
2 X2 3,0,0
```

Than you can access the elements containing comma for example, and apply `strsplit` again as mentioned by the other solution.

```
unlist(res)[grep(',',unlist(res))]
 "3,0,0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the numbers out using `strsplit`:

```
strsplit("3,0,0", ",")
```

It's not entirely clear if your data is actually in a data frame, or just a vector (people new to R have a tendency to call everything containing data as a "data frame"), but hopefully you can see how to apply the function.